# Meteor: Is there a reactive per-template scope?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I'm rendering the same Handlebars template in multiple (arbitrarily many) locations on the same page. Inside each template, I want a button to toggle the visibility of a div. When I save this state with `Session.set`, clicking one button obviously toggles all the divs in all the template instantiations which is not desired.

I could save the state in the data context of the template instance (which is bound to `this.data` in the `Template.myTemplate.rendered` and `Template.myTemplate.created` callbacks), but there are two problems with that.

1. `this.data` isn't a reactive data source, so will not propagate to the div
2. I don't have access to the template instance in `Template.myTemplate.events` (as discussed on [meteor-core](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteor-core/TA7_jDXs10Q))

Finally, I could somehow save it to a collection. But how would I uniquely identify the state for each template rendered? There might also be a hacky way with jQuery, but that's not the way I want to develop Meteor apps that are supposed to work with reactive templates. Especially, when that template gets more complex.

Am I missing something or is there really no equivalent to AngularJS's controllers that get passed a `$scope` for each template instantiation?

**Update**:
I was thinking of something like this.

template.html:

```
<template name="jsonObject">
    <input type="button" />
    <div class="{{hidden}}">content</div>
</template>
```

client.js:

```
Template.jsonObject.hidden = function(){
    var ret = "";
    if (this._hidden) {
        ret = "hidden";
    }
    return ret;
};

Template.jsonObject.events({
    'click input' : function(event, template){
        template.data._hidden = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Great question.  I'm missing this feature from AngularJS.

Answer (score 18):

All other answers are too complicated and/or outdated. As of Meteor 1.0, the recommended solution to maintaining per-template state is to use [reactive variables](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg) stored in the [template instance](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_inst):

> A template instance object represents an occurrence of a template in the document. It can be used to access the DOM and it can be assigned properties that persist as the template is reactively updated. [...] you can assign additional properties of your choice to the object.

Reactive variables are provided by the [`reactive-var` core package](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg):

> A ReactiveVar holds a single value that can be get and set, such that calling `set` will invalidate any Computations that called `get`, according to the usual contract for reactive data sources.

Your code becomes:

```js
Template.jsonObject.onCreated = function () {
  this.hidden = new ReactiveVar(false);
};

Template.jsonObject.helpers({
  hidden: function () {
    return Template.instance().hidden.get() ? 'hidden' : '';
  }
});

Template.jsonObject.events({
  'click input': function (event, template) {
    template.hidden.set(true);
  }
});
```

The HTML is the same as you'd expect:

```html
<template name="jsonObject">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>Hidden is {{hidden}}.</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I'm not sure the downvote was necessary.   I'm happy to delete my outdated answer.

Comment: @colllin: +1 for that. I tried to undo the upvote but "deleted posts can't be voted on", so I've upvoted another good answer of yours.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I achieved a per-template instance reactive source

I only want to ask the user for the reason for a dinosaur's extinction when its extinction status is set to extinct.

```
<template name="dinosaur">
   <label for="extinction-status">Extinction status</label>
   <select name="extinction-status">
     <option value="not-extinct">Not extinct</option>
     <option value="extinct">Extinct</option>
   </select>
   {{#if isExtinct extinctStatus newExtinctStatus extinctStatusDep}}
   <label for="extinction-reason">Reason for extinction</label>
   <input name="extinction-reason" type="text" placeholder="Why is it extinct?"/>
   {{/if}}
</template>
```

To reactively display the reason field, we add a `Deps.Dependency` to `this.data` in the template `created` function

```
Template.dinosaur.created = function() {
  this.data.newExtinctStatus = null;
  this.data.extinctStatusDep = new Deps.Dependency;
};
```

We listen for when the user changes the extinction status selection, and update the `newExtinctStatus` and called `changed` on our `extinctStatusDep`.

```
Template.dinosaur.events({
  'change [name="extinction-status"]': function(event, template) {
    var extinctStatus = $(event.target).val();
    template.data.newExtinctStatus = extinctStatus;
    template.data.extinctStatusDep.changed();
  }
});
```

In the helper we say we depend on the `Deps.Dependency` we are passed

```
Template.dinosaur.helpers({
  isExtinct: function(status, newStatus, statusDep) {
    if (statusDep) {
      statusDep.depend();
    }
    if (newStatus) {
      if (newStatus == 'extinct') {
        return true;
      }
    else if (status == 'extinct') {
        // No new status is set, so use the original.
        return true;
    }
  }
});
```

It is a bit of a hack involving adding to `this.data`, but it allows for per-template reactivity, useful for when you rely on data that has not been saved to something in a `Collection` yet.

Comment: Clever. I simplified it for an animation system, but the core of what you suggested worked very well -- i.e. putting the dependency as a property of this.data

Comment: [ReactiveVar simplifies the Deps code a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28386826/1269037).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER - METEOR 0.8.3**

Meteor now provides the `UI._templateInstance()` function, which gives access to the template instance in template helpers. This allows for a much cleaner implementation:

1.
In the below HTML code, remove `{{#with templateInstanceId=getTemplateInstanceId}}`

2.
Replace the JS code by this one:

```
var templateInstanceId = 0;

Template.divWithToggleButton.created= function() 
    { 
    this.templateInstanceId = ++templateInstanceId;
    };

Template.divWithToggleButton.events(
    {
    'click button': function(event, template) 
        {
        Session.set("visible", template.templateInstanceId);
        },
    });

Template.divWithToggleButton.visible= function() 
    { 
    return Session.equals("visible", UI._templateInstance().templateInstanceId);
    };
```

**FORMER ANSWER**
I had the same requirement in my project: uniquely identifying a template instance for using with `Session.set`.

Here is my simple hack, using context replacement and a 'sliding' unique instance id (more on this later):

Anywhere in client code, put:

```
var templateInstanceId = 0;

UI.registerHelper('getTemplateInstanceId', function()
{
    return templateInstanceId++;
});
```

Then use `{{#with templateInstanceId=getTemplateInstanceId }}` in templates you want to uniquely identify instances. With your example, it could be something like this (not tested):

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Div with a toggle visibility button. Use as a Block Helpers (with # instead of >) -->
<template name="divWithToggleButton">
    {{#with templateInstanceId=getTemplateInstanceId }}
    <div>
        <!-- The 'toggle visibility' button -->
        <button type="button">Toggle Visibility</button>

        <!-- The div content -->
        {{#if visible}}
            {{> UI.contentBlock}}
        {{/if}}
    </div>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

**JS (client code):**

```
Template.divWithToggleButton.events(
{
    'click button': function(event, template) 
    {
        Session.set("visible", this.templateInstanceId);
    },
});

Template.divWithToggleButton.visible= function() 
{ 
    return Session.equals("visible", this.templateInstanceId);
};
```

Now about this strange 'sliding' unique instance id:

This id is updated at each template rendering, I found no other way. **It means any new rendering will invalidate the unique id stored in the Session**. New rendering occurs if your div contains reactive data sources. Depending on your case, this can be a problem or not.

Comment: As of Meteor 0.9.1,`UI._templateInstance` has been renamed to `Template.instance`.

Comment: Things are [even simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28386826/1269037) as of Meteor 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think that discussion on meteor-core is outdated (though it is recent). [Per the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) (quoted below), this should be possible:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
   foo: function(event, template) {
      var _div = template.find('...');
   }
});
```

> The handler function receives two arguments: event, an object with information about the event, and template, a template instance for the template where the handler is defined. The handler also receives some additional context data in this, depending on the context of the current element handling the event. In a Handlebars template, an element's context is the Handlebars data context where that element occurs, which is set by block helpers such as #with and #each.

**Update**

Assuming each hideable div had a unique id, what if you tried something like this? I haven't tested it.

```
Template.jsonObject.hidden = function(){
    var _id = $(".classOfPossibleHiddenDiv").prop("id");
    return Session.get(_id) || false;
};

Template.jsonObject.events({
    'click input' : function(event, template){
        Session.set($(template.find(".classOfPossibleHiddenDiv")).prop("id"), true);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but that still leaves the problem that template.data isn't reactive.

Comment: Right. That makes sense. I updated my answer. This might be a bit hackish.

Comment: plus one for a hacky solution :) i guess if i have a global counter to generate the ids it works kind of..

Comment: underscore has a nifty `_.uniqueId` function that might be useful.

Comment: There's a [simpler solution as of Meteor 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28386826/1269037).