# Access template instance object properties directly from Spacebars

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

As [the Meteor docs state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752142/meteor-is-there-a-reactive-per-template-scope/28386826#28386826),

> A template instance object represents an occurrence of a template in the document. It can be used to access the DOM and it can be assigned properties that persist as the template is reactively updated. [...] you can assign additional properties of your choice to the object.

How can these properties be accessed from [Spacebar](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md) templates?

It's cumbersome to have to define helpers that do nothing more than

```
return Template.instance().myProperty
```

Comment: What if you defined a global helper returning `Template.instance()`?

Answer (score 4):

Just like @apendua said in comment, you can use global helper, this worked for me:

```
Template.mainPage.onCreated(function(){
  this.test = new ReactiveVar('stackoverflow');
});

Template.registerHelper('instance', function(context, options) {
  return Template.instance()[context].get();
});
```

and in HTML

```
{{instance 'test'}}
```

You could probably use `Template.currentData()` as well.

### Edit

According to [this article](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/template-instance) you can do in HTML something like:

```
{{Template.instance.test.get}}
```

so there is no need for global helpers, and it is accessible from Spacebars so no helpers required

Comment: OP states he doesn't want to define helpers. He wants to access the data "directly"

Comment: No, he doesn't want to create new helper every time he needs to return some template value

Answer (score 1):

OP wants to access the data directly without any helpers. You will need to store the data in `Template.currentData()` or `Template.parentData(n)`. Anything in those can be accessed as `{{myData}}` or `{{../myParentData}}`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use {{#with}}{{/with}}

for example

```
{{#with getObject}}
<h1>{{prop1}}</h1>
<h2>{{prop2}}</h2>
{{/with}}
```

and in helper

```
getObject:function(){
return {prop1:'some text prop1',prop2:'some text prop2'}
}
```